# Как исправить вылет в PyQT?

Tags: python, windows, qt5, pyqt5, pyqt

Имеется простенький Текстовый редактор. Столкнулся с проблемой: при нажатии на кнопку "Х" (красный крестик), в диалоговом окне выбора файла, получаю вылет:

"Программа Python не работает"

Код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QFileDialog, QApplication, QWidget, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QIcon


class Notepad(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.textEdit)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("..\\source\\python.png"))
        self.statusBar()

        openFile = QAction(QIcon('..\\source\\open.png'), 'Open', self)
        openFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openFile.setStatusTip('Open new File')
        openFile.triggered.connect(self.showDialog)

        saveFile = QAction(QIcon('..\\source\\save.png'), 'Save', self)
        saveFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        saveFile.setStatusTip('Save new File')
        saveFile.triggered.connect(self.saveDialog)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(openFile)
        fileMenu.addAction(saveFile)

        self.setGeometry(300, 200, 750, 400)
        self.setWindowTitle('Notepad')
        self.show()     

    def showDialog(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file')[0]
        f = open(fname, 'r')

        with f:
            text = f.read()
            self.textEdit.setText(text)

    def saveDialog(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Save file')[0]

        file = open(fname, 'w')
        text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        file.write(text)
        file.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Notepad()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Пришла мысль, что причиной является наследование от класса QMainWindow, но как решить вопрос я не придумал. Прошу помощи!

Comment: Не могли бы вы заменить картинку на обычный текст. Картинка будеть когда-то удалена и ваша ссылка станет битой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getOpenFileName - возвращает кортеж, где первый элемент - это путь до выбранного файла, так как в твоём случае файл не выбран - строка пуста. Нужно перед дальнейшими действиями проверить длину строки с путём к файлу:

```
def showDialog(self):
    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file')[0]

    if len(fname):
        f = open(fname, 'r')

        with f:
            text = f.read()
            self.textEdit.setText(text)
```

Comment: альтернативно: `filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file')`. Также, вместо `if len(seq)` в Питоне принято писать `if seq`. То есть `if filename: ..` говорит "если имя файла было дано, то .." В сторону: я понимаю, что вы код из вопроса код скопировали, но смысла файл вне `with`-конструкции не видно. Вместо этого можно `with open(filename) as file:\n set.textEdit.setText(file.read())` или `set.textEdit.setText(Path(filename).read_text())`